# How to get image from server in swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift

I am having problem in fetching image from the server, here is my code 
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var getImageOutlet: UIImageView!

let get_Image_URL = "http://172.16.1.22/UploadImage/displayImage.php"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.getImage()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func getImage(){
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://172.16.1.22/UploadImage/displayImage.php") else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
        }

        if let imageData = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getImageOutlet.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
}
```

how to fetch image from server with any other method my image is not displaying in my imageView can anyone help me with the problem ??

This is how my postman looks like when i execute it with the api link

```
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/harshilpatel@gmail.com_company-registration.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/shriyakshah@gmail.com_company-registration.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/johndoe@gmail.com_Image_Test.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/zara.larsson@gmail.com_Image_Test.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/_user-profile.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/ijk@gmail.com_user-profile.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/def@gmail.com_user-profile.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/mno@email.com_user-profile.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/Dhdnm_user-profile.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>
<img src='http://localhost/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration- 
API/v1/companyImages/abc@email.com_user-profile.jpg' 
style='height:40%;width:40%;'/>{"message":"Image displayed 
Successfully"}
```

My new Code with tableview :

```
import UIKit

class ImageTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

final let myURL = URL(string: "http://172.16.1.22/UploadImage/displayImage.php")

var imageArray = [ImageData]()
@IBOutlet weak var imageTableVieqw: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imageTableVieqw.delegate = self
    self.imageTableVieqw.dataSource = self
    self.downloadImage()
//        self.imageTableVieqw.tableFooterView = UIView()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
     func downloadImage(){
    guard let downloadURL = myURL else{ return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data1, response, error) in
        print("Downloaded")
        guard let data = data1, error == nil, response != nil else{
            print("Something went wrong")
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedimagedata = try decoder.decode(Images.self, from: data)
            print("ImageDATA=\(downloadedimagedata)")
//                print("image***=\(downloadedimagedata.images[1].imageV)")
            self.imageArray = downloadedimagedata.images
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageTableVieqw.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch{
            print("Catch wrong")
        }
    }.resume()
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell") as! ImageTableViewCell
    if let imageURL = URL(string: imageArray[indexPath.row].company_logo)
       {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data  = data{
               let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageCell.image = image
                }
            }
        }
        }

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

How my new API looks like:

```
{
"logos": [
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/harshilpatel@gmail.com_company-registration.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/shriyakshah@gmail.com_company-registration.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/johndoe@gmail.com_Image_Test.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/zara.larsson@gmail.com_Image_Test.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/ijk@gmail.com_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/def@gmail.com_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/mno@email.com_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/Dhdnm_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/abc@email.com_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/erp@email.com_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/tuv@email.com_user-profile.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/rohansoni@gmail.com_Image_Test.jpg"
    },
    {
        "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/qwe@email.com_user-profile.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

My model creation code:

```
import Foundation
class Images: Codable {
let images: [ImageData]
init(images: [ImageData]) {
    self.images = images
    }
}
class ImageData: Codable {
let company_logo: String

init(company_logo: String) {
    self.company_logo = company_logo
}
}
```

Comment: Refer This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift

Comment: I see no real problem with the code. Is the API actually returning an image?

Comment: @Kuldeep i will refer that link

Comment: @Sulthan I have updated my post with postman message

Comment: The API seems to respond with HTML and a piece of JSON. Doesn't seem to return an Image.

Comment: @Larme I am new with fetching image from the server can you let me know how should a postman look when i fetch image from server

Comment: @Kuldeep i have done as per your link but in my console i am getting this response ===>>>>> Begin of code
Download Started
End of code. The image will continue downloading in the background and it will be loaded when it ends.
displayImage.php
Download Finished

Comment: Well, if you paste the URL to your browser, *you should see the image displayed in your browser window*. If that does not happen, it's not an image URL.

Comment: @Sulthan I am getting this response in my browser

Comment: @AudreyRozario, you url doesn't return image url

Comment: @Kuldeep i have made my backend developer change the API according to the replies i have got here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually hit a `.php` file.To get image you have to hit an image file like `.jpg or .png extension` and also the `url` you hit is response with `HTML` data but it should response with `json or xml`.Keep a look on rest api.It's helps you to understand more.

Comment: i would like to know that if i want a list of images from my server then also i need to hit a file like .jpg or .png

Comment: look, you want a list of image.In your server site each image may store in a folder.So each image file has a path by which we can reach this image.So you need a list of path to get those image.And the way we get is a json response.

Comment: ok I have made my backend developer to change the api format as you said now i want to return image in tableview can you let me know how to do that

Comment: hit the link as you coded above.The code you do has no problem.The problem you have is the link.Hope it helps and accept any answer as correct if solve your problem.

Comment: my code is going in catch I changed my code because i wanted the images to come it tableview but it's going in catch

Comment: {
    "logos": [
        { "company_logo": "http://172.16.1.22/Book-My-BIM-API/Company-Registration-API/v1/companyImages/qwe@email.com_user-profile.jpg"
        }
    ]
} This is how my api looks now i have a list of images like this

Comment: so what's problem.parse json and hit the image link.and when you download an image from web make sure it's a background task not in your main thread.Read GCD it may help you about threading.

Comment: my code is going in catch and not displaying images and yes i will read about GCD

Comment: Please study some basics of how network calling work.How you store data in your model.there many tutorial in google.I just give a [likn](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud421) if you want to learn.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help till now but can you let me know why is it going in catch I have updated my code with my model creation in it too